# read conf file and make contents available to all files in package

Tags: python, global-variables, configuration-files

```
myMain.py
/myPackage
    file1.py
    file2.py
    confFile.cfg
```

myMain.py imports file1 and file2 etc. and it reads the confFile.
what would be the best way for the conf options to be visible in 
the whole package? i.e. for file1 and file2 to be able to read
the conf options. I do not want to pass a lot of variables around
in functions.

What I have right now is a confFile.py which i import into the files
and read the variables defined from it as they are required.

I am new to python and any suggestions are appreciated.

/Zaar

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to just have a python module `config.py` or `settings.py` and store those settings directly in those python files instead of the `confFile.cfg`.

Then you could just get anything you want by:

```
import config
config.my_specific_option
```